# Undefined on live server, but WORKS on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Google Map on the webpage with markers on it that has click listeners attached to them.

**Problem:** On **localhost**, when I click on a map marker, everything works as intended. However, after uploading to the server and trying the **live** version, clicking on the marker causes an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'listing_id' of undefined`.

Both `console.log` shows that `json` and `i` are defined...

**Console.log output**

> [ Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object ,
>   Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object , 
>   Object ,  Object ,  Object ,  Object ]
>
> i: 48
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'listing_id' of undefined

Why is this happening?

**JS Code**

```
$.getJSON(......., function(json) {

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[json[i].listing_id], 'click', function() {
            console.log('json: ' + json);
            console.log('i: ' + i);
            console.log('json[i].listing_id :' + json[i].listing_id);

            // Mark currently opened marker
            markers[json[i].listing_id].setIcon(base_url + 'images/template/markers/listing_black.png');

            //...
         });
     })(i);
 }

});
```

Comment: If you console.log a certain object, does it have a listing_id property?

Comment: I updated original post code with a 3rd `console.log`. The 3rd `console.log` generates the same undefined error on the live server, put outputs the correct value on the localhost. Puzzling...

Comment: What does the object look like, does it have any properties at all, or is it just the listing_id that is missing?

Comment: I probed it more, before entering the `google.maps.event.addListener()` function, json is the same on both live server and localhost. However, once the marker is clicked and we enter the `google.maps.event.addListener()` function, the number of objects inside json is only left with around 10 on the live server, while for the localhost, it remains at 150.

Comment: Not sure if it will have any effect, but what happens if you pass the json-data into the click-callback as well: `google.maps.event.addListener(markers[json[i].listing_id], 'click', function(json) {`

Comment: I tried passing json like as you said, and seems like `json` now contains the details (lat, lng) of the marker that was clicked

Comment: Alright, then skip that. Another idea would be to get rid of the self-executing function that wrap the `google.maps.event.addListener()`.

Comment: With the code being in the callback function of an asynchronous function, and we were to remove the self-executing function, will the variable `i` be the wrong `i` by the time the click handler uses it?

Comment: I checked the contents of `json` using `console.log` just before clicking on the marker, and right after clicking on it. Seems like a lot of the its contents are missing right after clicking....

Comment: Strange thing is this does not happen on localhost.

Comment: Oh man... I figured out what happened! Everytime the marker is clicked, I had another click listener where a `.post(...,{},function(data))` function is called, which fails on localhost due to the same origin policy thing, so the callback function for `.post()` was not execued. In the callback function, I had `json = $.parseJSON(data);` which on the live server overwrites `json` right after clicking on the marker but before the `console.log(json)` was called... The `.post()` function failed on localhost so it did not overwrite. THANKS CHRIS!

Comment: Great, glad you found it, started to run out of ideas here... lol!

Comment: ____________________:)                   _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't pass the data to the callback function.

Try changing your first line to this instead:

```
$.getJSON(......., function(json) {
```

Comment: Sorry, i did not add json into the code in the post.. json is in there in the actual code